# How to prove that the characteristic polynomial of this specific matrix is not the power of a linear polynomial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, free-groups, characteristic-polynomial

I was reading an algebra paper, and the problem that appeared to me is the following:

The authors defined a group $G = A \rtimes \left<x\right>$, where $A$ is a finitely generated free abelian group and $\left<x\right>$ is the infinite cyclic group and such that $x$ does not normalize any non-trivial cyclic subgroup of $A$. Then the element $x$ acts on $A$ in the following way for suitable integers $t_{i,j}$, given that $\{a_{1}, ..., a_{r}\}$ is the independent set that generates $A$:

$$x^{-1}a_{i}x = \prod\limits_{j}a_{j}^{t_{i,j}}.$$

Now, the authors defined the matrix $T = [t_{i,j}] \in GL_{r}(\mathbb{Z})$.

The characteristic polynomial $f(y) = \det(yI - T)$ is such that $f(0) = \det(T) = \pm 1$ (because $[t_{i,j}] \in GL_{r}(\mathbb{Z})$) and $f(1) \neq 0 \neq f(-1)$ - this part is ok, given that $x$ does not normalize non-trivial cyclic subgroups of $A$. Now the authors also say that $f(y)$ is not the power of a linear polynomial, "since the composition factors of $x$ on $\mathbb{Q} \otimes A$ cannot all be linear".

I simply could not understand this last part, and I don't know how to justify the fact that $f(y)$ is not the power of a linear polynomial. What does this last sentence mean after all?
If anyone could provide some sort of insight I would be really grateful.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
By definition, an element $x \in G$ normalizes a subgroup $H \leq G$ iff $xHx^{1} = H$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $f(y)=(X-a)^n$. It implies that The map $L_x:A\rightarrow A$ defined by $L_x(u)=x^{-1}ux$ verifies $(L_x-aId_A)^n=0$. This implies that $Ker(L_x-aId_A)\neq 0$, we deduce that there exists $u\in A, u\neq 0$ with $xux^{-1}=au$. This implies that $L_x$ normalize the non trivial subgroup generated by $x$. Contradiction.

Comment: What does $xux^{-1} = au$ mean? Wouldn't it be $xux^{-1} = u^{a}$? Also, I think you meant that $x$ normalizes the subgroup generated by $u$, but this is simply not true (by definition, we say that $x$ normalizes a subgroup $H$ iff $xHx^{-1} = H$, and in this case, if everything went right in your answer, we would have $x\left<u\right>x^{-1} = \left<u^{a}\right>$).

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, but I think that it still didn't work for me. Maybe if you could explain it better in the parts that I pointed. But thanks anyway.

Comment: $x^{-1}ux= u^a$ since the group $A$ is commutative I use the additive notation.

Comment: Ok then... but there is that other thing: $x$ does not normalize the group generated by $u$ with that definition I wrote in the edited part. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It probably has something to do with that tensor product that the authors cited, but I can't figure it out how to continue. Probably your idea appears in the argument.